# PHP glob() to count all image-files with $variable directory doesn't work

Tags: php, directory, glob

with PHP, I need to count all images in a certain directory, given by a variable $filedir, and store this count in a variable $imagecount.

Therefor, I'm using the following:

```
$fileurl = $file->url();
```

This variable gives the path to the file's directory like:
    /mnt/web5/d1/87/52146187/htdocs/bahrain/content/1-pavilion/3-phoenix-dactylifera

```
$imagecount = count(glob($filedir . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE));
```

This should count all files of the type jpg, jpeg, png, gif

As a result, I'm always receiving "0" for $imagecount. Does anyone know, what the problem might be? (There are some given image-files in this directory)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the path relative or should it be absolute ?

Comment: I commented on the answer below.

Comment: Then try: `glob("." . $filedir...` does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Now, I'm trying `count(glob('.' . $filedir . '/*.jpg', GLOB_BRACE));` with 3 .jpg files present and also this does not work... The result is "0"

Answer (score 2):

Use `chdir()` to set your desired directory.

```
echo getcwd() . "\n";  // where you start from
chdir($filedir);       // where you want to look
echo getcwd() . "\n";  // see if you actually got there
$image_count = count(
    glob('*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE)
);
echo $image_count;
```