# How can I find sizes of files in directory?

Tags: php, arrays, filesize

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$dir = $root.'/mphp/124/upload/uploads/';
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir,2), array('..','.','.htaccess'));
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.','.filesize($value).'<br>';
}
?>
```

However PHP displays this error (with exception for one file which size is succesfully displayed):
`Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /*name*/ in /*this php file*/ on line 6.`
Why does this happen?

Comment: I prefer to use `chdir()` so that I don't need to worry about the path. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42464318/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `$value` is the name of the file ( without the path ) -- in other words you need the path + the value. in this case `filesize($dir . $value)`

For reference I went and looked

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir

> Returns an array of filenames on success

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Function

```
 filesize('Your File Path' , 'Your File Name');
```

Comment: But not like this...

Comment: Use chdir() function

Comment: Yes, worked. I didn't notice the file which size was displayed was duplicated in the folder with the .php file, so that would quite explain the situation. Thank you anyway